# Invoking Overloaded Function on Google Mock

Tags: c++, googlemock

I'm attempting to test an abstract class using Google Mock. Following the [forDummies](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/ForDummies) guide, I've constructed a mock of my class:

**AbstractFoo.h**

```
class AbstractFoo {
public:
  virtual void setSize(int w, int h) = 0;
  void setSize(const QSize& s); // implemented as calling above function
}
```

**MockFoo.h**

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
class MockFoo : public AbstractFoo {
public:
  MOCK_METHOD2(setSize, void(int w, int h));
}
```

**FooTest.cpp**

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "MockFoo.h"

TEST(AbstractFoo, MethodSetSize) {
  MockFoo foo;
  EXPECT_CALL(foo, setSize(5, 5)).Times(1);
  foo.setSize(QSize(5, 5)); // this line produces compiler error
}
```

The marked line produces the following compiler error:

> C2660: 'MockFoo::setSize' : function does not take 1 arguments

My understanding is that since `MockFoo` extends `AbstractFoo`, it should inherit the `setSize(QSize)` method.  However, this does not appear to be the case.  How can I fix this?

*edited for code inaccuracies*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of your method in the mock class is wrong :

```
MOCK_METHOD2(setSize, bool(int w, int h));
```

and the base class has the method with this signature :

```
virtual void setSize(int w, int h) = 0;
```

I am not sure which compiler you are using, but that should be a compiler error.

Fix the signature, and the error should go away :

```
MOCK_METHOD2(setSize, void(int w, int h));
```

---

Additionally,

```
class MockFoo : AbstractFoo
```

should be

```
class MockFoo : public AbstractFoo
```

---

Your problem has nothing to do with googlemock library - but rather with c++. What you are trying to achieve is not possible because of [class.virtual]/1.

Next example demonstrates the same problem :

```
struct A
{
    A(int h,int l):x(h),y(l){}
    int x; int y;
};

class AbstractFoo {
public:
    virtual void setSize(int w, int h) = 0;
    void setSize(const A& s){setSize(s.x,s.y);}
};

class MockFoo : public AbstractFoo
{
public:
    void setSize(int , int ){}
};

int main()
{
    MockFoo f;
    A a(5,5);

    f.setSize( a );
}
```

You can solve this issue by renaming `setSize(const QSize& s)` method, or by casting `MockFoo` object to `AbstractFoo&` and then calling this method.

You can also take a look into [NVI](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface), since that it what it looks like you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for pointing those out.  Those are errors introduced as I constructed a shorter example than my actual code, and do not exist in my code, which is still producing the shown error.

Comment: @bdares After creating compilable example, I realized what exactly is the problem. That is how c++ works.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and especially for the workarounds!

Answer (score 3):

if you are messing around with member methods that are overloaded versions of each other, then you are likely to run into problems with gmock. Google mock declares each mocked function as individual functor objects and while you of course can overload functor objects, what you will normally do is overloading the individual operator()(...) methods inside the functor object.

I usually get around this problem by declaring a wrapper mock function and then call that from my overloaded function. The header will then look like this:

**MockFoo.h**

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
class MockFoo : public AbstractFoo {
  public:
    void setSize(int w, int h) {
      mocked_setSize(w, h);  ///< workaround to call the mocked setSize instead.
    }

    MOCK_METHOD2(mocked_setSize, void(int w, int h));
}
```

So now every call to `setSize(w,h)` is directed to your `mocked_setSize(w,h)` method. This means that now you will have to do the following in your unit test:

**MockFoo.cpp**

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "MockFoo.h"

TEST(AbstractFoo, MethodSetSize) {
  MockFoo foo;
  EXPECT_CALL(foo, mocked_setSize(5, 5)).Times(1);
  foo.setSize(QSize(5, 5)); ///< now this should compile cleanly.
}
```

This will avoid that google mock internally will generate an object with the name of the method you are trying to declare.